# call save function from another form

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

does anyone knows why this code is not working? On main form I have save function but whenever i click Save button message "nothing to save appears".

```
    public void spremiIzmjene()
    {
        try
        {
            this.bindingNavigator1.BindingSource.EndEdit();
            DataSet imaPromjene = this.dimproDataSet.GetChanges();
            if (imaPromjene != null)
            {
                int brojRedova = this.op_kontaktTableAdapter.Update(dimproDataSet.op_kontakt);
                MessageBox.Show("Izmjene spremljene: " + brojRedova + " red dodan.", "Uspjeh");
                this.dimproDataSet.AcceptChanges(); 
                this.dimproDataSet.Clear();
                this.op_kontaktTableAdapter.Fill(dimproDataSet.op_kontakt);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing to save", "No changes");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // msg
            this.dimproDataSet.RejectChanges();
        }

    }
```

I call this function from my insert form.
Problem: I need to open insert form, enter data into fields, close form (but not to write to db, only keep dataset changes) and then on form closing event call spremiIzmjene() on main form. But whenever i call that function dataset.HasChanges return false

[image: Screenshot]

thanks

Comment: `If no changed rows are found, the method returns null.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ey25we(v=vs.110).aspx Sounds like nothing changed.

Comment: I just updated my question with problem description.

Comment: when i put this code into insert form save button click event data is saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, because nothing has changed. In other words, if you had data bound controls, none of the values changed. If you were updating rows by hand, you probably called `AcceptChanges` when you shouldn't have. In short, when modifying data in a `DataTable`, which resides in a `DataSet`, you want to make those modifications but don't call `AcceptChanges` because that changes the `RowState` back to `Unchanged`.

Comment: @CarloŠtefanac, that's fine. As stated, *if you were modifying rows by hand.* In other words, in another method. In your case, leave the `AcceptChanges` where it was and fix your binding. You need to bind your controls to a `DataRow` in the `DataTable` so that the changes can be recognized; your binding isn't correct.

Comment: @CarloŠtefanac, have a look at this post here. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial